# How to tell DataTables where to insert the buttons export

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I wanna archive something like this with [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)
[image]

But I can't find a way how to tell datatable where to insert button copy, excel,PDF etc. Default insert button datatable will replace `sorting entries` like this

[image]

This is my code

```
<div class="box-header">
    <div class="buttonContainer"></div>
    <div class="pull-right">
       <button class="btn btn-primary form-button" id="addNew">Tambah Produk</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

and

```
var dTable;
    dTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "responsive": true,
      "buttons": [ 'copy', 'excel','csv','pdf'],
    });
```

I wanna insert `datatable buttons` in `buttonContainer`

I found a reference how to do that in here [dom datatable](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

but not quite understand how to implement it in my case

Please help

Comment: Can you post some jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option with the value `Bfrtip`.

```js
var dTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
   "dom": "Bfrtip"
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bAutoWidth": false,
   "responsive": true,
   "buttons": [ 'copy', 'excel','csv','pdf']
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Remember to add `l` too if you want to see the length-change control. Like this: `"dom":"Blfrtip"`