# Shiny datatable rowGroup actionButton collapse/expand

Tags: r, shiny, callback, dt

I have designed a basic Shiny App including a datatable with a `rowGroup` argument.

Now, I'd like to add an `actionButton()` that would collapse/expand all lines of the datatable on button press.

Currently, the code collapses by default all rows based on the `rowGroup`argument and each `rowGroup` can be opened one-by-one on mouse click (which is nice), but I'd also like to add a button that expand/collapse all rows simultaneously.

Here is a reproducible example (inspired from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761304/dt-collapse-all-row-groups-by-default/66774002#66774002)):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1", actionButton("expandButton", "Expand/Collapse"),dataTableOutput("my_table")) 
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = c('RowGroup',"Buttons"),
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 3), 
                 pageLength = 20, 
                 dom = 'tB',
                 buttons = list(list(extend = "",
                                text = "Collapse rowGroup",
                                action = JS("function (e, dt, node, config) {dt.rowGroup().dataSrc('').draw();}")))), 
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
        "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
        "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
        "});",
        "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
      ),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Would you have any suggestions (my understanding of javascript is extremely limited)?

Thanks,

C.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71075605/implementing-datatables-net-with-vite-and-vue-how-to-fix-datatable-is/74039112#74039112 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368360/make-a-download-button-in-shiny-app-that-saves-a-data-frame-in-an-excel-file-and/59108977#59108977

Comment: You need `extensions = "Buttons"`, `dom = 'tB'` (with **B**) and try `buttons = c(the_JS_Button)`

Comment: @phili_b Thanks for your reply!
Modifying the `buttons` argument for the following creates an action button that removes the rowGroup:
`buttons = list(list(extend = "", text = "Collapse rowGroup",action = JS("function (e, dt, node, config)` `{dt.rowGroup().dataSrc('').draw();}")))),`

How could I now change the javascript code to collapse/uncollapse all rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DT, except very recent, only the number of the column works.

On the callback you can bind the expand button.

Good job to have found options / buttons / action R Shiny DT equivalent of pure javascript implementation :)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1", 
               actionButton("expandButton", "Expand/Collapse"),
               dataTableOutput("my_table")
      ) 
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = c('RowGroup',"Buttons"),
      options = list(rowGroup = 
                       list(
                         dataSrc = 3 # disp
                       ), 
                     pageLength = 20, 
                     dom = 'tB',
                     buttons = list(
                       list(extend = "",
                            text = "UnGroup rowGroup disp",
                            action = JS("function (e, dt, node, config) {dt.rowGroup().dataSrc('').draw();}")
                       ),
                       list(extend = "",
                            text = "Group rowGroup disp",
                            action = JS("function (e, dt, node, config) {dt.rowGroup().dataSrc(3).draw();}")
                       )                       
                     )
      ), 
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
        "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
        "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
        "});",
        "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))",
        "$('#expandButton').on('click', function(){",
        "  $('#my_table').toggleClass('hidden')",
        "});"
      ),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Dear @phili_b, thank you very much for your reply. 
Your example works perfectly and the second button "Group rowGroup disp" is exactly what I was looking for. 

Do you know how the code could be adapted so that when pressing on the button it does: 1) Expand rows if they are all collapsed AND 2) Collapse rows if they are all expanded ?

Comment: For me the button does what you ask, so I don't understand or you have to explain again :)  (In general you have to post s new separate question)

Comment: A path of idea `$('#my_table').find('.dtrg-group').each(function() { Something to test and toggle hidden; });`

Answer (score 0):

By adding/removing a `'hidden'` class to the rows, all groups can be expanded/collapsed via buttons

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1",
               dataTableOutput("my_table")
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = c('RowGroup',"Buttons"),
      options = list(rowGroup =
                       list(
                         dataSrc = 3 # disp
                       ),
                     pageLength = 20,
                     dom = 'tB',
        buttons = list(
          list(extend = "",
               text = 'Expand <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>',
               action = DT::JS("() => {
                                $('#DataTables_Table_1').find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
                             }")
          ),
          list(extend = "",
               text = 'Collapse <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>',
               action = DT::JS("() => {
                               $('#DataTables_Table_1').find('.even').addClass('hidden');
                               $('#DataTables_Table_1').find('.odd').addClass('hidden');
                               }")
          )
        )
      ),
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
        "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
        "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
        "});",
        "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))",
        "$('#expandButton').on('click', function(){",
        "  $('#my_table').toggleClass('hidden')",
        "});"
      ),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The critical part being the action in the buttons

```
buttons = list(
  list(extend = "",
       text = 'Expand <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>',
       action = DT::JS("() => {
                                $('#DataTables_Table_1').find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
                             }")
  ),
  list(extend = "",
       text = 'Collapse <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>',
       action = DT::JS("() => {
                               $('#DataTables_Table_1').find('.even').addClass('hidden');
                               $('#DataTables_Table_1').find('.odd').addClass('hidden');
                               }")
  )
)
```

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to get the ID of the table (`DataTables_Table_0` in your example), but if you just have one table you could skip that search and use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

A fuller example: https://gist.github.com/jonocarroll/6de8d5b4b7dbe33001820ba1939ebac0