# Shiny datatable rowGroup buttons action R to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatable, dt

This is a follow up of a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74800879/shiny-datatable-rowgroup-actionbutton-collapse-expand) I wrote.

I have a simple Shiny App relying on `DT::renderDataTable` to generate a table based on the `mtcars` dataset.

I have included an action button that enables to expand all rows when pressed (based on the `rowGroup` extension).

Since the column index that is used as the `rowGroup = list(dataSrc = ColNum)` argument is defined programmatically (i.e., `ColNum <- 3`), I would like then to pass this integer value from R to javascript as an argument of the `action = JS(function())`.

Since my understand of javascript is very limited, I have tried to follow this [thread](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) but unsucessfully...

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1",
               # actionButton("expandButton", "Expand/Collapse"),
               dataTableOutput("my_table"))
    )
  ))

# Column corresponding to the rowGroup argument
ColNum <- 3

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Send ColNum to the browser
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("column-integer", jsonlite::toJSON(ColNum))
  })

  # Generate the table
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = c('RowGroup',"Buttons"),
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = ColNum),
                     pageLength = 20,
                     dom = 'tB',
                     buttons = list(
                       list(extend = "",
                            text = "Expand rows",
                            action = JS("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('column-integer', function (e, dt, node, config, ColNum) {dt.rowGroup().dataSrc(ColNum).draw();})")))),
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
        "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
        "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
        "});",
        "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
      ),
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for the support,

C.

I tried to modify

```
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("column-integer", jsonlite::toJSON(ColNum))
  })
```

as

```
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("column-integer", ColNum)
  })
```

But it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ColNum` as a global JavaScript variable and change its value with the Shiny message handler:

```r
js <- "
var ColNum = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('column-integer', function(x) {
    ColNum = x;
  });
});
"

tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js)))
```

Since `ColNum` is a global variable it will be found in the action of the custom button:

```js
function(e, dt, node, config) {
  dt.rowGroup().dataSrc(ColNum).draw();
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply, unfortunately this doesn't work. The code runs, the table gets printed by then when I press on the custom "Expand rows" button nothing changes (the lines are not expanded).

Comment: @CorentinWicht Maybe one has to not include the js code in `tags$head`.

Comment: isn't it what `tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js)))` already does? 
If not, could you adjust your response to match your comment? thanks!